# Merge two columns on two conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to merge two columns into one column.

The challenge is that I want to join them together only on two conditions.

- If there's something occupied on the salary column, we don't join;
- If the comp column doesn't have monetary sign `£`, which means there's no numeric value, they don't join.

I first tried paste() but I don't think it's the right case and it's also not joining two dataframes as they're just two columns in the same dataframe. Is there a way to do this conditional join?

Dataset:

```
                        salary                                    comp
19              £9.18 per hour                                    <NA>
20 £35,000 to £50,000 per year          Self employed, Commission Only
21 £29,000 to £30,000 per year                                    <NA>
22 £20,000 to £35,000 per year                                    <NA>
23 £29,000 to £31,000 per year                                    <NA>
24          £65 to £80 per day                                    <NA>
25          £65 to £75 per day Opportunity to become a permanent role.
26                        <NA>                                    <NA>
27                        <NA>              £18,000 + Bonus & Benefits
28                        <NA>                NMW + Overtime and Bonus
29                        <NA>                 Depending on experience
30                        <NA>                    £21,892 - £24,157 pa
31                        <NA>              £38,890 -£44,503 per annum
```

```
structure(list(salary = c("£9.18 per hour", "£35,000 to £50,000 per year", 
"£29,000 to £30,000 per year", "£20,000 to £35,000 per year", 
"£29,000 to £31,000 per year", "£65 to £80 per day", "£65 to £75 per day", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), comp = c(NA, "Self employed, Commission Only", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Opportunity to become a permanent role.", NA, 
"£18,000 + Bonus & Benefits", "NMW + Overtime and Bonus", "Depending on experience", 
"£21,892 - £24,157 pa", "£38,890 -£44,503 per annum")), row.names = 19:31, class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
                        salary                                    comp
19              £9.18 per hour                                    <NA>
20 £35,000 to £50,000 per year          Self employed, Commission Only
21 £29,000 to £30,000 per year                                    <NA>
22 £20,000 to £35,000 per year                                    <NA>
23 £29,000 to £31,000 per year                                    <NA>
24          £65 to £80 per day                                    <NA>
25          £65 to £75 per day Opportunity to become a permanent role.
26                        <NA>                                    <NA>
27  £18,000 + Bonus & Benefits              £18,000 + Bonus & Benefits
28                        <NA>                NMW + Overtime and Bonus
29                        <NA>                 Depending on experience
30        £21,892 - £24,157 pa                    £21,892 - £24,157 pa
31  £38,890 -£44,503 per annum              £38,890 -£44,503 per annum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join involves 2 different tables that are merged together according to some key. Your expected output is just replacing values in column salary according to some condition, this can be done via a simple `mutate`:

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate(salary = if_else(is.na(salary) & grepl(pattern = "£", x=comp), comp, salary))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. `str_detect()` inside `ifelse()` is from `{stringr}`. Let me know if this is what you need. :-)

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(salary = c("£9.18 per hour", "£35,000 to £50,000 per year", 
                                "£29,000 to £30,000 per year", "£20,000 to £35,000 per year", 
                                "£29,000 to £31,000 per year", "£65 to £80 per day", "£65 to £75 per day", 
                                NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), comp = c(NA, "Self employed, Commission Only", 
                                                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, "Opportunity to become a permanent role.", NA, 
                                                                  "£18,000 + Bonus & Benefits", "NMW + Overtime and Bonus", "Depending on experience", 
                                                                  "£21,892 - £24,157 pa", "£38,890 -£44,503 per annum")), row.names = 19:31, class = "data.frame")

as_tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(salary = ifelse(is.na(salary) & str_detect(comp, "£"), comp, salary))
```